# How can I access methods of dynamically created variables?

Tags: powershell, scripting

I am fairly new to PowerShell and I try to do something like this:

```
$sshictcred = New-Object 
System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("username",$password)

New-Variable -Name $Server"session" -Value (New-SSHSession -ComputerName 
$Server -Credential($credentials))

New-Variable -Name $Server"stream" -Value ("`$"(Get-Variable -Name 
$Server"session" | % Name).Session.CreateShellStream("PS-SSH", 0, 0, 0, 0, 1000))
```

MY PROBLEM:

At the last command I get the error "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression". I guess this is because it is missing the $ sign because it should generate the name of the previously set variable.

So I create a New "I believe dynamic" variable from a previously generated variable.

Output I want after creating new var -Value:

```
 $PREVVARNAME.Session.CreateShellStream(xxxxx)
```

Simplified I *think* I want a string generated like this:
    "$" output of command GET-VAR as string "session"

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a look at the help center ([How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)) or take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Please edit the question and explain in plain English what you are trying to achieve. The code sample is a bit strange, so there's likely to be much simpler way to get desired outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not have access to those cmdlets but it looks like you are just trying to create some dynamic variables here and use some associated methods.

First lets just capture the output from the first dynamic variable and save it.

```
$serversession = New-Variable -Name $Server"session" -Value (New-SSHSession -ComputerName $Server -Credential($credentials)) -Passthru
```

So now `$serversession` would be a `System.Management.Automation.PSVariable` which at a minimum would have a name and value property.

Now we can use the *value* of `$serversession` to perform our next operation

```
$serversession.Value.Session.CreateShellStream("PS-SSH", 0, 0, 0, 0, 1000))
```

That *should* do it.

Personally I would question the need for dynamic variables here. If you are planning on having multiple concurrent sessions maybe..... but there are many ways to deal with that.

Like a hashtable for example

```
$sessions = @{}
$sessions["$Server"] = New-SSHSession -ComputerName $Server -Credential($credentials)
$sessions["$Server"].Session.CreateShellStream("PS-SSH", 0, 0, 0, 0, 1000))
```

Comment: Please understand that I just started learning scripting with powershell so I have difficulty keeping up with some scripting jargon.

The idea is indeed building multiple SSH sessions (because that is the same trick for every server but then  "do something" on server 1 but "do something else" on server 2 is tricky for me. So for each server I need to maintain a session and I need to be able to access that session to perform actions. 

Am I explaining this right?